# How to do tutorial in app and launch it just on first start up in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to find out how to do tutorial on first start up of app in xamarin. When I try to search that it throws just a plenty tutorials how to start programming in xamarin. Do you have any ideas how can i add tutorial to my app but just on first start up?

Comment: check for a flag at startup - if it has not been set then execute your tutorial UI and set the flag so that it does not run again.  You can also use Essentials Version Tracking to detect if this is the first run of your app

Comment: How can I set flag and use it to run just when is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Essentials [VersionTracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms)

```
if (VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver)
{
  MainPage = // your Tutorial page
}
else 
{
  MainPage = // your standard app first page
}
```